# Can you set HTML canvas styles without using a string?

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas

I made a web based proof of concept that draws thousands of colored divs all over the screen, and animates the whole page by changing the color of each div each animation frame.  (JS doing the work obviously.)  The performance is, shockingly, nowhere near as bad as I thought, but still kinda bad.  Upon inspection using the Chrome browser profiler, I discovered the performance bottleneck is, *not* shockingly, due to having to generate the color of *every* div by building a string for each one, every animation frame.  String concatenation is famously slow.  I see that over 90% of the performance for this web app is being eaten up by a single line of code, and it's the code that generates the string for style color.

For clarity, this is the line in question:

```
// currentBox properties red, green, and blue are simple integers
element.style.backgroundColor =
  `rgb(${currentBox.red}, ${currentBox.green}, ${currentBox.blue})`
```

I was looking into drawing on an HTML canvas instead, hoping the draw/fill color would be able to be defined with something other than a string to cut down on this performance bottleneck.

Is there any way to color a div/canvas style (particularly the color) other than with a string?  Or do I need to go all the way into WebGL land or something?

I'm referencing MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Applying_styles_and_colors).  This makes it seem like strings are the only option for CSS or canvas styles.  But I'm holding out hope that someone knows another trick.

Comment: Look into [`ImageBitmapRenderingContext`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageBitmapRenderingContext), [`ImageData`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData), and [`ImageBitmap`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageBitmap).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what "string" you are referring to, but when you set anything via `element.style` property, you can only use strings, whether it's a color name `red` or hex `#FF0000` or RGB `rgb(255, 0, 0)` it's still a string. Perhaps it's not the "string" that is bottleneck in your case, but the way the color is generated?

Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value for more information about different types of color formats.

Comment: This was my fear.  If a string must always be used, then a web app is probably just the wrong place to move forward with this project.  I've updated the original post to be more clear based on this answer, thank you.

Comment: Maybe instead of changing color via `element.style` you could change color via `element.className`? (colors table set via CSS)

Answer (score 0):

It may simply be due to the fact you are trying to animate thousands of elements every frame. That can be taxing. I've ran into issue with just animating 500-1000 elements. I think canvas would handle that animation better. of course without your code it's hard to determine exactly what it is you are doing. I can only offer an example of running animations on thousands of rectangles using canvas API.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const cw = canvas.width = innerWidth;
const ch = canvas.height = innerHeight;
let rectArr = [];

class  Rect {
  constructor(x, y, w, h) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    this.c = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
  }
  draw() {
    this.c = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    ctx.fillStyle = this.c;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
  }
}

function createRects() {
  for (let i=0;i<2000;i++) {
    rectArr.push(new Rect(Math.random()*cw, Math.random()*ch, Math.random()*50, Math.random()*20))
  }
}
createRects();

function animate() {
  for (let i=0;i<rectArr.length;i++) {
    rectArr[i].draw();
  }
}

setInterval(animate, 300)
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: I didn't show much surrounding code because the question is limited to the performance bottleneck which the browser confirmed was limited to a single line and appears to be limited to the generation of a string.  Your solution generates/coerces string values as well, this could be where your bottleneck is.